# How to wait 2 seconds for input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I im programming tv remote control using javascript and need when user press number 1 function waits 2 seconds if user press one more time 1 (1 channel or 11 channel or 111channel).

i write this function but it gets on display only `11111111` in loop here is my code:

```
 function chChannel(pressed) {
     setInterval(function () {
         if (lengthCS < 3) {
             inputChannel += pressed;
             lengthCS = inputChannel.length;
         }
     }, 2000);

     // call function to change channel using variable value inputChannel for ex. 011
 };
```

Any solution please?

So function need to wait 2seconds and then after 2seconds it gets value of pressed numbers in variable InputChannel so that i can then call function to change channel to number from Value InputChannel.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: Sounds like you want a [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "setTimeout".

```
var Timer;

function chChannel(pressed) {
    clearTimeout(Timer);
    Timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (lengthCS < 3) {
            inputChannel += pressed;
            lengthCS = inputChannel.length;
        }
    }, 2000);

    // call function to change channel using variable value inputChannel for ex. 011
};
```

Comment: Apologize, i have wrong described. I need function that gets how many times is key pressed on remote control in period of 2seconds...and then call function changechannel. So when user press 011 within 2seconds variable inputChannel gets value 011

Answer (score 1):

Listening to keypresses and counting them is one well documented thing, but, in context with the actual topic, I would say, there is no correct Waiting method, other than to end the script with a timeout call being set to a function that repeatedly checks, whether the Time to wait has passed by, if not then selftrigger with setTimeout in eg. 100ms, if yes then call a function that continues the main program.
The Waiting thread may then also check and count keypresses, eg. in global variables as a basic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like underscore's debounce function, would make things a lot simpler all round.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

May be something like this might work, on phone can't test it myself...

```
var inputChannel;

 function chChannel(pressed) {
     if (inputChannel <= 3) {
         inputChannel += pressed;
     } 
     else {
        inputChannel = pressed;
    }
    _.debounce(someFunction, 2000);
 };
```

As long as debounce keeps getting called within the delay it will not execute, and only execute once after the delay.

Comment: i think that debounce is what i need...but if YOu could provide me some code..i will be very thankful. i have not previous working with debounce in javascript so that is something new for me.